# Google Sheet API php curl get request

Tags: php, curl, oauth, google-api, google-sheets-api

I am using google oauth v2 HTTP request to obtain the access toke which is working fine, I'm getting the token, but when using the token to access a spreadsheet I'm getting a 403 error.

This is the request code I am using.

```
$get = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1bHKgQLgqB4PfjRUVPkYk5_L7aQOtZGOkhJbr_RFxQQY?access_token='.$access_token;

$ch = curl_init();  

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$get);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET' );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($output);
```

And this is the return with the header

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Vary: X-Origin
Vary: Referer
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Date: Tue, 15 Nov 2016 13:13:09 GMT
Server: ESF
Cache-Control: private
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="36,35,34"
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Origin,Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{
  "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The caller does not have permission",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

I've tired to make the sheet public but that makes no difference to the error. The error is not displaying on the API console either.

These are the scopes I am using:

```
{
   "iss":"dev-537@mortgagetest-149109.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
   "scope":"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive    
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets 
    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly",
   "aud":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
   "exp":'.($time+3600).',
   "iat":'.$time.'
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like the user you are authenticating doesn't have access to that sheet.   Also make sure that that you have used the correct scope to authenticate the user.

Comment: I've turned it on in the API console. Is there anywhere else I have to enable the sheet for that user?

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem

The sheet I was trying to access needed sharing with my client ID (email address)
Right click on the sheet in the google drive and share with the email address.

Posting this for anyone with the same problem.